# Converted from WGS84 to sperical mercator so how do i now proceed to plot correctly on googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wgs84, mercator

How do I plot using latitudes and longitudes in WGS84 to those of Google maps spherical mercator using googlemaps API V3 javascript?

I do not have a problem converting my lats&longs to their Mercator equivalent however I do not know how to proceed from here.

This is very critical for me since my markers are off which am attributing to projection issues.

Help me proceed.

Comment: Google Maps might use Mercator projection, but points are plotted using WGS84 coordinates. The API handles placing points on the projected map. I think a demonstrator might help if your positionings are wrong.